# Drawing the neckline for a Head and Shoulders pattern

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

[Neck line for Head and shoulders pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xmzp.png)

[image]

The book **Technical Analysis of the Financial Markets** explains how to draw a neckline for H&S pattern.

In the diagram, a flatter trend line can be drawn under the  reaction lows (points B and D). But instead, the author uses points D and G to create the trend line and it starts above point B. What is the reasoning behind doing this?

Comment: Line BD would be steeper, not flatter. Right? Line 2 was drawn to connect Points D and G for whatever reason. Does the book not explain why?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer there is no explanation in the book for connecting points DG instead of points BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to create a trend line is to connect the early points (B and D) and project forward, as the author did with the other trend line.

Either the author made a small  inadvertent mistake or instead, he knowingly created a trend line with points D and G to make it appear that this H&S pattern was precisely correct.